# JAX-WS logging & timestamp

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, weblogic-10.x

I am using JAX-WS in WebLogic and I was able to enable the message logging by using following parameters (as specified at https://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#logging):

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

The log entries however do not contain any timestamps so I have almost no information about when each message was received/sent.

Is there any way to add timestamps to the resulting log entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution for this.

The only thing that must be done is to redirect stdout logging to WebLogic logging system by checking “Redirect stdout logging enabled” in Advanced logging section of your managed server’s configuration (e.g. Logging -> General -> Advanced).

This will add timestamps to the SOAP message logs.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to configure log messages format:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%4$s: %5$s [%1$tc]%n
```

More about configuration options could be found here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html

Comment: I am having some trouble to make this work in WebLogic (make the managed server use this parameter since Admin Console managed server's Startup params do not let me add quotes).
I will let you know if it works in my case as soon as I persuade the WebLogic to cooperate.